# Pass parameters to covergroups in SV Testbench

Tags: system-verilog, testbench

I am trying to create a parameterized `covergroup` in my testbench as follows:

```
covergroup CG (input int id); 

    cp1 : coverpoint tb.gen_block_mem[id].var_x[3:0];

endgroup : CG 

CG CG_0  = new(0);
CG CG_1  = new(1);
```

This fails in elaboration as the `id` variable is not a constant. Is there a SystemVerilog workaround for this so that I can instantiate covergroups just like parameterized modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `tb.gen_block_mem` is a `generate` block, you'll have to put the covergroup in another generate block

```
for(genvar id=0;id<MY_P;id++) begin : cg_block
 covergroup CG; 
  cp1 : coverpoint tb.gen_block_mem[id].var_x[3:0];
 endgroup : CG 
 CG cg  = new;
end : cg_block
```